# How to write a new number to the end of a text File

Tags: c#

I'm trying essentially add one number onto the end of a text file without overwriting that file. Currently I've tried to read from a file, store that data into a string, then add into a list, add a new integer into the list and then write into the file.

```
M = @"C:\Mental.txt";      
StreamReader content = new StreamReader(M, Encoding.Default);
string m = content.ReadToEnd();
List<int> num = 
  new List<int>(m.Split((string[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(int.Parse));
num.Add(4);
content.Close();
content.Dispose();

var s = num.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(M,s);
```

If you have any other suggestion of how to write the code or why it isn't working I'd appreciate it. I've tried many different variations of this code, but the same issue keeps occurring where the output is the same data my file has, but then the addition of numerous '4's where I only want one to be added.

I.E 
if my file previous contained:

```
1
2
3
```

it will now contain

```
1
2
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
...etc
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything fundamentally wrong with this code.  Is there something else besides what you have here?

Comment: Yes there is lots more than just this, as pointed out by Mayur, below, it's looping. I was so focused on this being the issue I'd forgotten where the code was being called from and the fact that it updates often which would explain the proliferation of the number being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String filePath = @"C:\Mental.txt";

File.AppendAllText(filePath , "content");
```

try this method

EDIT:

> your code runs fine on my machine, can you please check that your
>   function is not called over and over again or in loop

Comment: Thank you! How stupid of me. Yes it is, I'd completely disregarded that as an issue. Using XNA and I initially put into the game update method just for testing purposes so I could get the code working because it's not being used yet. I'm just glad there is nothing wrong with it. Was losing my mind.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to read the whole file before appending to it. Try something like this:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("filename"))
{
  w.WriteLine("something to append");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I initially started with this, but clearly became out of hand trying to get a different result. Thank you.